# How can I construct a universal transformation using Clifford+T gates?

Tags: unitarity, clifford-group

How can I construct, using Pauli, Hadamard and $T$ gate, a universal transformation $U$ such that $U|0\rangle$ has a less than $\frac{\pi}{4}$ complementary angle with $|0\rangle$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that you might do it is as follows. Consider the unitary sequence $V=HTHT$. Because it's unitary, we can write it in the form
$$
V=e^{i\gamma}e^{-i\theta\vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}=e^{i\gamma}(\cos\theta I-i\sin\theta \ \vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma})
$$
where $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{n}=1$. If you work through the details, you'll find that
$$
\cos\theta=\cos^2\frac{\pi}{8}
$$
if memory serves.

This means that I can write
$$
V^k=e^{i\gamma k}(\cos(k\theta) I-i\sin(k\theta) \ \vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}).
$$
So long as you pick a value of $k$ such that $|\cos(k\theta)|$ is close enough to 0, you're sorted (if you let $k$ get large enough, you can get arbitrarily close to 0). I'd probably just do this numerically (although if you want to get sophisticated, you could use continued fractions on $\theta/(2\pi)$).

I'm assuming that your condition is supposed to translate into a mathematical statement of
$$
|\langle 0|U|0\rangle|\leq\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$
If this is indeed the case, then $k=2$ may be fine, although $k=3$ is even safer as
$$
\cos2\theta\approx 0.457107, \cos3\theta\approx-0.0732233.
$$
Note that I've skipped an important step here because I've only been looking at $\cos(k\theta)$, not at
$$
|\langle 0|U|0\rangle|=\sqrt{\cos^2(k\theta)+n^2_z\sin^2(k\theta)}.
$$
Still, I claim that $n_z<1/\sqrt{2}$ so that so long as I find a small enough value of $\cos(k\theta)$ it will work out fine.